# Create extension attribute to quote_item table

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extension-attributes

I am trying to create extension attribute to `quote_item` table but in 
module-quote I haven't seen any `QuoteItemInterface`, but there is `CartItemInterface`.  I tried with that

*extension_attributes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="sample_field" type="string">
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

but not working ,
how can I set and get extension attributes to `quote_item` table ? How can I check the field is created or not ?

Comment: Please refer this link for add custom field to quote item using extension attributes. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284951/magento-2-add-extension-attributes-in-quote-item

Answer (score 1):

You should see getters and setters for your sample_field in generated folder. See Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartExtensionInterface. Its generated automatically. Also when you implement extension attributes, be aware that you persist the data yourself. To add this attribute to the entity you should figure out a way to load your value. Best approach is to use plugins or events